# ASP .NET Web API 2 FromForm model binder attribute?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

Does ASP.NET Web API 2 (not core) contain also something like `[FromForm]` attribute for binding the action? Or can I add the dll from ASP.NET Core to a normal ASP.NET Web API 2? {

> ```
> "Message": "The request entity's media type 'multipart/form-data' is not supported for this resource.",
> "ExceptionMessage": "No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'FooBindModel' from content with media type
> ```
>
> 'multipart/form-data'.",
>       "ExceptionType": "System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException",
>       "StackTrace": "   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent
>   content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger
>   formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger
>   formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)" }

Answer (score 2):

No, only `FromUri` and `FromBody` is available for ASP.NET Web API 2. You can look at the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api).

Also, why would you try to implement `FromForm` to ASP.NET Web API 2. You can simply configure your form action as `GET` and `POST` and pass the data to Web Api. In my opinion, it would be over engineering.

Comment: @Stormcloack well I am currently using Postman to send my data (integers and a file)... however i am not able to bind my integers with my bind model...

Comment: Why ? Just post your file and integers. What would FromForm provide you something in this case ?

Comment: @Stormcloack .... I am saying that if I use `[FromBody]` I am not able to bind the data...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you actually understand these attributes or what they do. `[FromBody]` means that you are providing a serialization (JSON, XML, etc.) or basically any other content that doesn't have an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` mime type (image or other file type). If you're sending a normal form post (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request body) to a param marked as `[FromBody]`, of course it won't bind, because you're explicitly telling it that it should be expecting something other than what you're sending.

Something like `[FromForm]` is actually pretty useless anyways, as the default is to expect `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which is all this attribute would do. Long and short, just don't decorate your action param with anything.

Comment: well my bind model still doesn't bind the primitive types, no idea why... although I am able to get my file(image) from `HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];` PS: I am using ASP.NET NOT core, in my WebApiConfig I have this line of code `config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/form-data"));` because I get an awful error if I don't have it(error in question)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use FromUri for your model and also use HttpContext.Current.Request.Files for getting files from the header

this is your model that set in the Params section
[image]

this is your file that set in the Body section ==> from-data
[image]
and this is final result
[image]